# facing NoClassDefFoundError on Android While using LWA(Login with amazon) with .NETMaui

Tags: xamarin.android, maui, login-with-amazon

I have used LWA on Xamarin forms before and it's working fine. but when trying to use the same library for Android (3.0.6) with .NET Maui (.NET 8) I'm facing below NoClassDefFoundError and com.Amazon.Identity.Auth.Device.Api.Workflow namespace also looks not found but not getting build error. these issues not there while implementing Xamarin Forms with Android. how to resolve the issue

> ex    {Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;  ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" on path:

Comment: Anyone to help?